# How to get the minimum or maximum element in a vector of structures in C++, based on some field in the structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, max, stdvector

How can I get the minimum or maximum element in a vector of structures in C++, based on some field in the structure?

For example:

```
struct Size {
    int width, height;
};
vector<Size> sizes;
```

And now I want to solve that based on *width* and create a new vector for that. And then sort based on *height* and create a new vector for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
vector<Size> sizes;
...
vector<Size> sortedByWidths(sizes);
vector<Size> sortedByHeights(sizes);
sort(sortedByWidths.begin(), sortedByWidths.end(), 
    [](Size s1, Size s2) {return s1.width < s2.width;});
sort(sortedByHeights.begin(), sortedByHeights.end(), 
    [](Size s1, Size s2) {return s1.height< s2.height;});
```

Comment: I have no idea how all the other answers overlooked the fact that OP wanted 2 new vectors, lmao

Answer (score 21):

In C++11, you can use the [`std::minmax_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) standard function, which (given a pair of iterators) and possibly a custom comparator (that would allow you to define the field on which the ordering is based), will return you an iterator to the minimum and an iterator to the maximum element, packed in an `std::pair`.

So for instance:

```
#include <algorithm> // For std::minmax_element
#include <tuple> // For std::tie
#include <vector> // For std::vector
#include <iterator> // For global begin() and end()

std::vector<Size> sizes = { {4, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 2} };

decltype(sizes)::iterator minEl, maxEl;
std::tie(minEl, maxEl) = std::minmax_element(begin(sizes), end(sizes),
    [] (Size const& s1, Size const& s2)
    {
        return s1.width < s2.width;
    });
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/1FdqY6).

Answer (score 21):

You can use [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) with a suitable functor:

```
bool cmp(const Size& lhs, const Size& rhs)
{
  return lhs.width < rhs.width;
}
```

then

```
auto min_it = std::min_element(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), cmp);
auto max_it = std::max_element(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), cmp);
```

In C++11 you can replace `cmp` with a lambda expression.

**See also**: [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Answer (score 5):

Solution using std::minmax_element with lambda expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Size {
    int width, height;
};

int main()
{
     std::vector<Size> sizes;

     sizes.push_back({4,1});
     sizes.push_back({2,3});
     sizes.push_back({1,2});

     auto minmax_widths = std::minmax_element(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(),
         [] (Size const& lhs, Size const& rhs) {return lhs.width < rhs.width;});
     auto minmax_heights = std::minmax_element(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(),
         [] (Size const& lhs, Size const& rhs) {return lhs.height < rhs.height;});

     std::cout << "Minimum (based on width): " << minmax_widths.first->width << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Maximum (based on width): " << minmax_widths.second->width << std::endl;

     std::cout << "Minimum (based on height): " << minmax_heights.first->height << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Maximum (based on height): " << minmax_heights.second->height << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::min/std::max/std::minmax _element` with comparator.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

Comment: What do you mean by "with comparator"? Can you elaborate in your answer (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Well, comparator is actually usable slang (it's actually comparision function in std). From cppref (I have link to it in answer): comp - comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if a is less than b.

And no, answer should not appear as it was written today, just cause it was written in 2013.