# How to find the maximum value in an array of structures?

Tags: c, data-structures, max

How to get the max value in a structure? I have tried to create a simple program but I'm having issues with the `if` statement or variable, since I cannot determine the winner or candidate number which has the highest score.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 

struct Candidate{ 
float Score; 
short Number; 
}candidate1[5]; 

main(){ 

int i,n,highest; 
for(i=0;i<5;i++){ 

printf("Candidate Number: "); 
scanf("%i",&candidate1[i].Number); 
printf("Score: "); 
scanf("%i",&candidate1[i].Score); 

highest=candidate1[i].Score;    

for (n=0;n<5;n++) 

if (candidate1[i].Score>highest); 
} 
printf("Highest Number: %i\n",highest); 

system("pause");    

}
```

Comment: Do you understand 2D arrays in C at all? If not, I recommend hitting a good tutorial or book since this is absolutely basic.

Comment: You really need to learn basic C/C++ syntax. `if(); }` isn't anywhere close to valid.

Comment: 2D array ? you used 1D array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the minimum or maximum element in a vector of structures in C++, based on some field in the structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772477/how-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-element-in-a-vector-of-structures-in-c-base)

Answer (score 2):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Candidate {
    float Score;
    short Number;
}candidate1[5];

int main(void){
    int i, n, highest = 0;
    n = sizeof(candidate1)/sizeof(*candidate1);
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        printf("Candidate Number: ");
        scanf("%hi", &candidate1[i].Number);
        printf("Score: "); 
        scanf("%f",&candidate1[i].Score);
        if(candidate1[highest].Score < candidate1[i].Score)
            highest = i;
    }
    printf("Highest Number: %f\n", candidate1[highest].Score);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

,

Answer (score 0):

The most common idiom for finding the max of type `<T>` (double, int, whatever) from an array of structs `<S>` goes as follows

```
<S> array[numElements]; //defined and allocated earlier.  Has a score `<T> score`
<T> bestScore = array[0].score;
int bestIndex = 0;
int i;
for(i=1;i<numElements;i++) {
    if(array[i].score>bestScore) {
    bestIndex = i;
    bestScore = array[i].score;
    }
}
//do things with bestScore and array[bestIndex];
```

If you have a 2D array you can replace the single for-loop with a double for loop, and use an additional bestIndex variable for the second dimension.

If the array may contain 0 elements it is sometimes common to set bestScore to a minimum possible value and loop from 0 to `numElements`.